# Show UITabBar only on UITabBarController.viewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I'm doing it in all tab controllers:

```
(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
}
```

-

```
(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
}
```

And it's working when I'm going forward controller by controller, but on back way my TabBar disappearing.

Comment: well, when you go back, it also runs the `viewWillAppear` for the viewController you will go back to, so it runs the `hidden = NO`.

Your rootViewController(s) must not set it hidden on `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: when I go back from controller2 to controller1, at first called controller1's viewWillAppear then controller2's viewWillDisappear. But I can figure our the right way to do what I need.

Comment: what if you used `viewDidAppear´ or `viewDidDisappear´ depending on witch you want to appear last

Comment: I have tried and it works, but the TabBar blinking.

Answer (score 0):

The UITabBar is disappearing when going back, because the `viewWillDisappear:` method gets called, which executes the `self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;` line. However, I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to accomplish, so I'm not sure how to provide a solution other than removing the offending line of code.

Comment: I have UITabBarController with 2 controllers: Controller1 and Controller2. In both controller I have add these:(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
}
-

(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
} and when I'm going from controller2 to controller1, my tabBar gets disappeared, cause of it is that at first called controller1's viewWillAppear then controller2's viewWillDisappear.

Comment: I want to see tabbar only on UITabBarController.viewControllers, on all other screens it should not be shown

Comment: If you have your View Controller structure set up properly, when the UITabBarController is removed from the screen, it will automatically remove the UITabBar since the UITabBar's view is contained in the UITabBarController's view. So it's possible that your view structure is improperly arranged.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do the trick.
edit: since it did not work try this solution and you said that you only want to show on UITabBarController

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];

  if([self isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]])
  {
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
  }else{
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think there should be generic solution.

Comment: does it work as you want? if it does i will think of an elegant way.

Comment: let me see if i got it correct when you go forward it works, but when you go back you want the bar to be hidden but it is visible?

Comment: when I go back I want the bar to be visible but it is hidden?

Comment: see my edit. is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for try, but no. I want to see tabbar only on UITabBarController.viewControllers, on all other screens it should not be shown.